# How can I print unique line base on particular column value using awk?

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have a comma separated file with multiple fields.

Example:

```
candidate1,12,56,ATTG
candidate2,45,90,ATTG
candidate3,90,140,ATTG
candidate4,2,36,AGCT
```

So, does anyone know the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by unique line? As far as I can tell, each of your lines is unique. Could you show us your expected output? Do you want only _one_ of the ATTG lines?

Comment: I agree. Please include what you would like to see being outputted from the above and explain why.

Answer (score 4):

Say you need to print unique lines based on column 1 (`candidate1`, `candidate2` etc). Note that this prints the first instance of a line with `candidate1` etc. To print unique lines based on column 2, change `$1` to `$2` below.

```
awk -F, '!($1 in arr){print} {arr[$1]++}' file_name
```

Answer (score -1):

If all the fields are comma separated like this one

```
1, candidate1,12,56,ATTG
2, candidate2,45,90,ATTG 
3, candidate3,90,140,ATTG 
4, candidate4,2,36,AGCT
```

Then you do something like this one

```
$ grep -E 'candidate1|candidate3' file_name | awk -F, '{print $0}'
1, candidate1,12,56,ATTG
3, candidate3,90,140,ATTG
```

another example for a single line

```
$ cat filename | egrep 'candidate3' | awk -F, '{print $0}'
3, candidate3,90,140,ATTG
```

Comment: I deleted you mention of `awk` taking comma as default since it certainly does not on my system and I have never heard of it doing so. Perhaps it does for your `awk` implementation but is is not a general rule.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because your `awk` is doing nothing besides print the line. You are using `grep` to find presence in the line, but the question is about particular column values (which `awk` is well suited for).

Comment: to jordanm, the question was to print unique line based on column value. So, my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, but @jordanm's question still stands, what is your `awk` supposed to be doing? It does not change the output of `grep` in any way. In any case, you are not looking for anything unique, you are just printing ALL lines that contain "candidate3", combined with a useless use of gawk and a useless use of cat. Your solution is basically `grep 'candidate1\|candidate3'`.

Comment: @mrahman, No it does not print unique lines based on column value. It prints lines matching a regex pattern. What if he wanted `90` from column 3? If you replaced your regex with "90" you would get lines 2 and 3.